# Extract page from .pdf with PHP

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, extract

Is it possible to extract one or more pages from a .PDF-file, and save each page as a .JPG / .PNG / ...?

I already found ImageMagick but I want to know if there are any solutions where you don't need to install any extentions / plugins to PHP. I'm currently using PHP5.

Thanks a lot!

Niels

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing built into PHP for reading PDFs (there is for creating, as of php 5).  You can find some classes out there which will do it, and you won't have to install a PEAR module, just include the file.  Alternately, you could try and use imagemagick from the command line with exec or backticks, a lot of hosts already have it installed for use in the shell.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about creating an image from pages in pdfs, but you can use xpdf to read text from pdf files in php: http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/about.html

Something else you may want to look into is fpdf: http://www.fpdf.org/ which may have the features you're looking for